# Yii 1: Could not find driver error when connecting to microsoft sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, yii

I successfully tested that my PHP can connect to my MS SQL SERVER.

```
<?php

$server = 'SRV-MEXAL';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'mexal_db_usr', 'password_changed');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
} else {
    echo "Works <br>";
    $OK = mssql_select_db ("at6_rp");

    echo $OK ? "ok" : "ko";

}
?>
```

Using this script I got both `Works` and `ok`, so connection and db selection are both working.

I tried to configure my db connection into Yii 1 `main.php`

```
"mexal_db" => array (
        'class'                 => "CDbConnection",
        'connectionString'      => 'sqlsrv:Server=SRV-MEXAL; Database=at6_rp',
        'enableParamLogging'    => false,
        'username'              => 'mexal_db_usr',
        'password'              => 'password_changed',
        'charset'               => 'utf8',
    ),
```

But when trying to instantiate it, I got this exception

> CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver' in /var/www/httpdocs/test1.phonix.it/yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:399

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: HI @realtebo : My suggestion didn't worked ?

Comment: Hi ! sorry, we didn't checked SO until now. Yes it worked. I approved and marked as best answer

Comment: Hi. You don't know how much you *relieved* me. Glad to help. I also faced similar problem. `:D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have **php.ini** inside your `project folder`. (In `yii2`, i am having inside `web folder`. In `yii1`, I don't know where **php.ini** file is located.)
So, please find your **php.ini** file of your `project folder`.

Inside **php.ini**, search for `pdo_mssql.so`.

```
;extension=pdo.so
;extension=pdo_mssql.so
```

Remove `;` from it. Like

```
;extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mssql.so
```

Restart your server. It will work.

For more info, check this [could not find driver - Yii](http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2015/07/yii-cdbexception-could-not-find-driver.html)